# Where will discussion on the Spring 2016 Apple Event be hosted?

Tags: discussion

Apple's 10 a.m. PDT event will be streamed to a handful of OS/browser combinations. Is there anyplace on Ask Different where people will discuss things both live and after the event?

- http://www.apple.com/apple-events/march-2016/

Answer (score 1):

The primary place to discuss things will be in the main chat room:

- http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat

If people would like to add feeds of other coverage below or in a different answer, edits and posts are most welcome!

Apple's stream is hosted at http://www.apple.com/apple-events/march-2016/ and requires an Apple TV app or specific browser:

- Safari on iOS 7.0 or later, a Mac with Safari 6.0.5 or later on OS X v10.8.5 or later
- a PC with Microsoft Edge on Windows 10
- Apple TV (2nd or 3rd generation) with software 6.2 or later or an Apple TV (4th generation)

Press live coverage is announced at:

- http://live.arstechnica.com/apples-march-2016-event/
- https://www.macstories.net/tag/march-21/